# Using JSON_TABLE on ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, json, oracle

create table JSON_TAB (JSON_VAL CLOB);
-- tried to add the constraint like this CONSTRAINT JTE_CK check (JSON_VAL is json) butt says it expects null so I didn't create it for now.

I am trying to execute the statement

```
SELECT JT.Ime, JT.Broj, JT.Pozicija     
  FROM JSON_TAB JTE,     
       JSON_TABLE (JTE.JSON_VAL, '$.players[*]'                 
       COLUMNS (Ime VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.name',                        
                Broj NUMBER PATH '$.number',                        
                Pozicija VARCHAR2 PATH '$.position')) JT ;
```

and receiving an error SQL command not properly ended. 
JSON_VAL is a CLOB!
Is it a problem with syntax, data type or something else?

I took the example from youtube tutorial and entered it manually.

ORACLE version is 12.1.0.2.0.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement for your table including all check constraints. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Also: what is your exact Oracle version (`select * from v$version`)

Comment: That should work, although it would help if you posted the exact code you use to generate the table.  This works for me: `create table JSON_TAB (JSON_VAL CLOB, CONSTRAINT JTE_CK check (JSON_VAL is json));`

Comment: All code above is working properly on the local version of ORACLE DB (ver. 12.2.0.1.0). Guess some properties are different between local and remote DB.